# Trying to sum two compile time tuple integer sequences

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

If you're keeping track of my question history, I'm updating a dimensional analysis library for the sake of ditching a nightmare of macros and learning C++11, variadic templates, and meta programming and functional programming paradigms. For the life of me, this stuff is still magic.

Anyway, I have tuples of exponent constants that define physical units.

```
template<int... I>
using make_dimension = std::tuple<std::ratio<I>...>;

using scalar_dimension = make_dimension<0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>;
using length_dimension = make_dimension<1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>;
using time_dimension = make_dimension<0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0>;
```

This is (part) of a library that models the SI units. You can only multiply unlike units, you can additionally add like units and scalars. These libraries are dandy in that they cause compile time errors if you mix units inappropriately. There are >400 units and most of them are defined in terms of other units. When multiplying units, exponents are added, and when dividing units, exponents are subtracted. So to define velocity, I would love a means of expressing:

```
using velocity_dimension = divide_dimensions<length_dimension, time_dimension>;
```

And that should be functionally equivalent to writing:

```
using velocity_dimension = make_dimension<1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0>;
```

I've been Googling, but I just don't know the terminology to land some hits. The closest I've found was a for_each that applies a function to elements of a tuple at runtime... And it's kind of blowing my mind, so I can't quite figure out how to turn it into a compile time iteration over the elements. 'make_dimension' above was explained to me a moment ago and it blew my mind, but I recovered. I'm kind of bugged asking for a handout, so does anyone have any good resources for learning this stuff? I'm having a hard time believing I'm the only one remotely interested in doing this.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [`boost.units` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)?

Comment: *"You can only multiply unlike units"* So, no m², no m/s² etc.? Why?

Comment: Here's a quick example of a transform for a pair of tuples: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5f03a72538ce8c5 Since this is a basic function for type lists, you'll find some implementation in many TMP libraries. The interface I used in my example is quite awkward (but it integrates nicely with `std::ratio_add`); I'd suggest you try using `constexpr` functions instead.

Comment: @dyp, this metaprogramming is for defining the units and it doesn't apply to actually using the units. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I should rename that metafunction to divide. So "dividing" velocity by time again will get me acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dyp's solution in the comments uses a recursively instantiated template. While that's one of the most general techniques for variadic templates, in this case recursion is probably overkill, as the entire set of transformations can be performed in a single pack expansion that expands two parameter packs simultaneously:

```
template<template<class, class> class, class, class>
struct tuple_transform;   // undefined

template<template<class, class> class Transform, class...Ts, class...Vs>
struct tuple_transform<Transform, std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Vs...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<Transform<Ts, Vs>...>;
};

template<class T, class U>
using divide_dimensions = typename tuple_transform<std::ratio_subtract, T, U>::type;
```

Note that the above assumes that `Transform<T, U>` is an alias for the desired resulting type. This matches the behavior of `ratio_add` etc. - they are alias templates for the resulting `std::ratio`, so `typename ratio_add<...>::type` is not necessary.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a0d9d9d21182b3e).

Comment: Well I just haven't metaprogrammed in a while, and my skills are rusty ;) +1

Comment: I understand most of this, but man, my attempts were nowhere near close to this. Do you have a link to a resource I can study? @dyp, I wish you didn't delete your answer. If it worked, I'd have liked to see it anyway. I'm trying to learn this stuff and level up my skill set.

Comment: @MatthewReddington Huh? I never posted a answer here.. I only left a comment with a link of an implementation below your question..

Comment: @dyp, sorry, I didn't realize that until after the comment. I was reading from the bottom up and saw your link last. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

While T.C.s answer is correct you can simply take [std::integer_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (which is C++ 14 but can be simply implemented) instead of ratio and tuple which (in my opinion) don't really fit und use a constexpr functor for manipulation. 
Now your code should look like the following (which I didn't try to compile):

```
template<int... I>
using make_dimension = std::integer_sequence<int, I...>;

template<class Functor, class Dim1, class Dim2>
struct transfrom;

template<class Functor, int... Dims1, int... Dims2>
struct transform<
  Functor, 
  std::integer_sequence<int, Dims1...>, 
  std::integer_sequence<int, Dims2...>
> {
  static_assert(sizeof...(Dims1)==sizeof...(Dims2), "wrong dimensions");
  static constexpr Functor f;
  using type=std::integer_sequence<int, f(Dims1,Dims2)...>;
};

struct add {
  constexpr int operator()(int l, int r) const { return l+r; }
};
struct sub {
  constexpr int operator()(int l, int r) const { return l-r; }
};

template<class T, class U>
using divide_dimensions = typename transform<sub, T, U>::type;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough info,  but it looks like (1,0,-2,0,0,0,0) would be what you would need for acceleration. The 1 represents meters and the - 2 would represent division by seconds squared just as a negative exponent does in math.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Velocity is the first derivative of the speed equation, acceleration is the second, they're not the same thing. But yes, you are absolutely correct.